# Windows 2003 Server - Check Disk (chkdsk) is skipped during reboot

Tags: chkdsk

I have a Windows 2003 Standard Server, where Disk C: needs to be fixed with "chkdsk c: /f".
Usually when the server is rebooted, the check-disk is executed.
But this server skips the check-disk.
I already checked the registry.
It looks correct, concerning its settings.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\BootExecute
autocheck autochk /p \??\C:
autocheck autochk *

I already looked on Microsoft KB and search internet via google.
I wasn't able to find any answer to this issue.
All topics I found, where how to skip check disk program during start-up.

The Windows 2003 Standard Server is having the latest SPs and fixes by MS Website-Update.
The server is hosted on VMware 5.x.

Thanks for hints.

Best regards

Carlos Behlau

Answer (score 0):

You can boot from a Windows 7 disc or ISO file.
Select repair
Goto command prompt
chkdsk /f or chkdsk /R
depending on the type of damage.

As for why it skips it, do you have any stuck keys?  If you press any key even accidentally it will skip it.  To double check I would unplug the keyboard and use the mouse to do "shutdown and restart"